# jQuery 'find' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a set of nested `<div>` and on completion of the page load need to take action on the inner `<div>` of each of the outer `<div`>

In the `.ready()` of the page, I iterate through each of the `$('.outer').each()` calling the `doSomething()` function, which then attempts to `find()` the `<div class='inner'>`.

The problem is that the `.find()` method is failing with

> Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Below is the *view source* (from IE11) to demonstrate the issue.

**Markup**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        3
    </div>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".outer").each(function () { doSomething(this); })
    })

    function doSomething(divO) {
        debugger;
        var divI = divO.find("inner");
        console.log(divI);
    }
</script>
```

When the debugger breaks, evaluating `divO.tagName` on IDE (Visual Studio) it says that it is in fact a `Div` tag

Comment: what will be the output you expect from this code??

Comment: `divO.find("inner")` should be `divO.find(".inner")` (missing a dot)

Comment: `div0` is not a jQuery object. Just a DOM object... Use `$(div0).find('.inner')` to solve your problem.

Comment: `$(divO).find('.inner');`

Comment: @user1474602 - In this example, it's pretty pointless but demonstrates the issue without having to post my entire markup. In my real situation, i get access to all the child objects.

Comment: Curious on the -1 for question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
var divI = $(divO).find(".inner");
```

Comment: what will be the output you expect from above code with your changes??

Comment: Thanks very much indeed